# CosmosDB ST_DISTANCE Query not working as intended

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

So I've been trying to use the CosmosDB Query Function 'ST_DISTANCE', I've following their documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-st-distance) but it's not working, I've trying to query only Users that are in a radius of 1KM, but it's querying anything.
The actual difference between these 2 coordinates is much more than 1km

The query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM user u
WHERE ST_DISTANCE(u.location, {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates':[-25.131999881000644, -46.84260389576425]}) < 1000
```

What's it's finding:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "Test",
        "location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -24.171999881000644,
                -45.84260389576425
            ]
        },
    }
]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what "it's not working" means. You've shown a query, and you've shown a return value. Which part isn't working? What's incorrect about the return value?

Comment: The actual distance between the 2 coordinates is 5km,
sorry

Comment: Solution found, i had to multiply the value by 100, like the following query:

WHERE ST_DISTANCE(u.location, {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates':[-50.131999881000644, -23.84260389576425]}) *100 < 1